# Google Smart Lock for Passwords - is federated credential password visible to app? (e.g. when saving user's Facebook or Google Sign-In actions)

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

I was wondering if there is a security issue here ? Any app who uses the google smart lock will know the users google,twitter, etc account credentials right ? take a look at this google tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials) and in the credentialsRetrieved call back the Credential object has the users user name and password which the app can access.  But now the app knows the users google or twitter account ? Here is the code im talking about:

```
 private void onCredentialRetrieved(Credential credential) {
    String accountType = credential.getAccountType();
    if (accountType == null) {
        // Sign the user in with information from the Credential. 
//right here we have the users login credentials, dont we ??  There exposed. 
        signInWithPassword(credential.getId(), credential.getPassword());
    } else if (accountType.equals(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)) {
        // The user has previously signed in with Google Sign-In. Silently
        // sign in the user with the same ID.
        // See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/
        GoogleSignInOptions gso =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestEmail()
                        .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .setAccountName(credential.getId())
                .build();
        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr =
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        // ...
    }
}
```

So what im seeing here is that the Credentials object can expose the users password.  I realize the credentials are needed to continue the login process but is this a choice the user makes when they turn on smart lock ?

worse case: Imagine user enables smart lock and i make an app that uses smart lock. Now i gain access to the users twitter account credentials and do malicious things. How to protect user ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I work on the Smart Lock team at Google, hope this answers your question:

In the case of Google, Facebook, Twitter, or other "federated" credentials, the password for these Identity provider accounts is not stored in the credential. The password field on such credentials is empty and the "credential" only serves as a pointer as to which identity provider the user used for the given app. The idea is that saving and retrieving such a credential will enable the app to know that the current user has an existing account and should use a particular sign-in method (and could automatically sign the user in by triggering the respective flow, or help customize the UI so the user signs in with the appropriate method when they return).

Note that as of the current version of Play Services (8.4), the API will throw an error if an app attempts to construct and save a credential with both an account type and a password set; third-party apps should not be asking for or storing passwords for identity providers. Only the app's first-party password for the current user used to sign in to the service itself should be stored in the credential via the API, and should not have an account type set in that case.

In the example code of the question, the Google-type credential is used to programmatically trigger a Google sign-in flow (see the `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn()` call, and the full sample [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/credentials-signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/credentialssignin/MainActivity.java)), i.e. automatically signing the user in with Google as though they had clicked the Google sign-in button, since they had a credential with type "Google" stored.

In general, also note that apps can only retrieve credentials that have been saved from the app itself (identified by the package and certificate signature on Android) or in Chrome for an verified and associated website (see [details](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites)). This means that the app may only access data which it stored on behalf of the user (perhaps on another device, the idea being that the Smart Lock API facilitates retrieving authentication details across devices), or a username and password that the user entered for an associated website and opted to save with Google via Chrome's password manager.

Please leave a comment if that answers your question or you need any more information!

Comment: I could not find any information on how this API is secured since it is not an authenticated API call to play services.

You mention that the package & certificate signature are part of the equation, but how do you prevent mobile malware or software on a rooted device from spoofing apps?  Or someone just calling the API endpoint directly and providing the public strings you are looking for?  I presume there's something more to it...  

What's different about the network API request from App A vs. App B that is used to prevent App B from seeing App A's stored credentials?

Comment: Looking at the HTTP requests that smart lock is making, it appears as if all that is required to request a credential is:

* an OAuth token for the google account where passwords are stored (play services gets one for you automatically)
* the credential ID string
* an android:// application URI string

It's not clear yet where the credential ID comes from (how a caller knows which credentials are stored to display for resolution) to know secret that is.

It's also not clear how the url aka signonRealm value is generated to know if it is predictable.

Can you shed some light on these?

Comment: How can I find all the trusted device list from my Phone through android API call? Is this even possible or not.